# Should I, or can I use an: 'if __name__ == "__main__:" style construct but within an imported package or module?

Tags: python, design-patterns, import, package, namespaces

The simple python file `hello.py` is executed in the top level environment as main:

```py
#hello.py
def hello(input):
    print(f"hello, {input}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello(input = 'world!')
```

I know from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) and from [previous stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), that this pattern is somewhat of a formality in standalone scripts and simple packages, but it is good practice and can be important to prevent your script from being executed if it were to be imported as a module without the `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition.

I now have a module `foobar.py` either installed or temporarily added to sys.path, and I want to import it in `hello.py` and then for example, execute a function or instantiate some classes it defines during the import, (or perhaps later in the main script):

```py
#foobar.py
def foobar():
    print(f"foo bar baz")
```

Is it anywhere written in the docs, or implied that I can or should include the following:

```py
if __name__ == 'foobar':
    foobar()
```

in a similar manner to `if __name__ == '__main__':` but within files for execution as an import?

Doing this to guarantee execution of the `foobar()` function during the import, as opposed to simply calling `foobar()` either at the end of the `foobar.py` file or after its import, from within `hello.py`, which would to my understanding execute the function in all cases I can see!

Similarly, should I also include a blank:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

in modules and scripts which I never intend to be run as main? are there any obvious gotchas to avoid when doing this?

Comment: If `foobar.py` is not intended to be used as a standalone script, you don't need to do anything. you could do something like `if __name__ == '__main__': print("Don't run foobar.py by itself")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something on import, you should not put it in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guards, and I've never seen anyone check for their module name instead. That is specifically meant to NOT execute when imported, but only when run as a script. Also, don't include the blank with the `pass`, it's useless.

If you want to initialize your module on import, just do it in the top level. It would be a good idea however to keep stuff like that to an absolute minimum, and ,e.g., to keep any init logic in a function that is called in one place, to keep everything organised.

But if init is necessary, better to let the caller do it explicitly I'd say